# I cannot write file to hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop

I create three virtual machines. I used with one master, one slave and client node. And then I wrote java program in client machine.This program is used for writing file from client local file system to master hdfs.

I used `hadoop` is my client host name and `server1` is my namenode host name

Here is my code:

```
Configuration configuration=new Configuration(); 
InputStream inputStream =new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("HadoopFile.txt")); 
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://server1:9000"),configuration); 
OutputStream outputStream = hdfs.create(new Path(hdfs://server1:9000/home/hadoop/HadoopF.txt)); 
try { IOUtils.copyBytes(inputStream,outputStream,4096,false); }
```

After I run this program, I encounter error like:
Call from `hadoop/127.0.0.1` to `server1:9000` failed to connection exception

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: better, you can add the code block that you tried...

Comment: Configuration configuration=new Configuration();

Comment: Configuration configuration=new Configuration(); InputStream inputStream=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("HadoopFile_txt"));  FileSystem hdfs=FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://server1:9000"),configuration); OutputStream outputStream=hdfs.create(new Path(hdfs://server1:9000/home/hadoop/HadoopF.txt)); try { IOUtils.copyBytes(inputStream,outputStream,4096,false);

Comment: please insert your code as a code block in the question, not as a comment. See "help" for informations how to format your code and how to ask a good question

Comment: What errors do you get? Add them to the question